# Are there any cms system in asp.net mvc like drupal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins

I'm new to asp.net mvc world. Are there any cms system based on asp.net mvc like drupal (php, cms, plugin modules). I dont like dotnetnuke because they use webform and difficult to extends.

thanks

Comment: Basically what I feel is that there are no low-administrative-impact  .net-based CMSes out there at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't think DNN was difficult to extend, but I don't have much experience with it. ASP.Net MVC wise there isn't a huge amount, which isn't surprising considering it's not actually out yet :-)

The main, if rather simple, one is [Oxite](http://www.codeplex.com/oxite) which is on CodePlex. It wasn't considered a particularly "good example" of MVC when it was first released, but there's been quite a lot of refactoring help from the community so it's worth looking at. It is only a relatively simple blogging thing though, rather than a full on CMS, so don't expect Drupal :-)

Answer (score 3):

Without having too much Drupal experience, [Umbraco](http://www.umbraco.org/) is a nice choice if you want .NET (despite the fact that they have an animated favicon). There's professional support also if you need it.

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised nobody mentioned [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/).

> ### Basic Orchard Concepts
>
> Orchard is a Web CMS, which essentially aims at helping you build web
> sites from existing pieces. Those pieces come in a few different sizes
> and shapes that need to be well understood if you're going to be
> productive with them. This article will go through those pieces and
> explain their names and behavior.

More info: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Basic-Orchard-Concepts

Comment: Also, Orchard is based on ASP.NET MVC, and a lot of its modules have been inspired from Drupal. Let's copy the best ;)

Answer (score 2):

[BeerHouse](http://www.codeplex.com/TheBeerHouse/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx).

From their website:

TheBeerHouse is a website developed with pure ASP.NET 2.0 which includes a number of features and modules that you expect from a typical CMS / e-commerce website, such as:

```
* Layout with user-selectable themes.
* Membership system with registration, login, profile setup and complete administration.
* Content management system for publishing and syndicating articles and photos, with support for categories, comments, rating and profile-based personalization.
* Opinion polls with support for multiple active polls and archived polls.
* Mailing lists with support for HTML and plain-text newsletters, background transmission and real-time AJAX-based feedback.
* Forums with support for multiple categories, custom pagination, avatars, signatures, moderation, and complete administration.
* E-commerce store with support for real-time credit card processing, with support for multiple categories, percentage discounts, zoomable pictures, ratings, availability display and more.
* Homepage personalization with webparts.
* Localization.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently playing around with the N2 cms. I've not got my head fully around it yet, but you can plug it into web forms or asp.net mvc (they have some sample sites for both platforms). It can use a wide variety of database platforms as well due to nhibernate. It basically sorts out the back end so you can concentrate on the front. [N2 cms click here](http://n2cms.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend to use MojoPortal, it has a great Framwework and it works perfectly on Linux and Windows :) the url is => http://www.mojoportal.com/

Answer (score 1):

you can also have a look at: http://cmsmvc.codeplex.com/ which is a CMS built using asp.net mvc with plugin and theme support

Answer (score 1):

There is a project going on to port Drupal to .NET platform named [Drupal.NET](http://drupalnet.codeplex.com) which is currently under development.